# I installed pandas using pip but when I tried to run it I got ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pandas

I installed pandas using the command `pip install python` into my virtual environment. However, when I tried to import it using `import pandas as pd` I got the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: is your virtual environment activated?

Answer (score 1):

You must use `pip install pandas`. NOT `pip install python`.

Answer (score 1):

pandas does not come with python.  You should use `pip install pandas` or follow the installation guide [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/install.html)

Answer (score 1):

I hope that's a typo. Though `pip install pandas` is correct command to install pandas.